# django multiple values for keyword 'template'

Tags: django, django-urls

Is It possible in django 1.4

```
url(r'^(comment|review|feedback|suggestion)$',direct_to_template,{'template':'sample.html'}),
```

I tried and got

```
direct_to_template() got multiple values for keyword argument 'template'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're capturing the value from the URL - comment, review etc - and sending that to the template, but also hard-coding the template variable as "sample.html". But direct_to_template only expects one parameter, which is the template, so both values are being sent to the same parameter.

I'm not quite sure why you are doing this, but you could avoid capturing the value:

```
r'^comment|review|feedback|suggestion$'
```